# C# Threading Query

Tags: c#

I'm very new to threading, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but would appreciate some assistance. I have the following code to run when the user clicks the mouse; it basically runs some path-finding code and moves the player.

However, my problem is when I click the mouse again while the thread is running, it causes issues. Is there a way to stop the previous thread and start a new one when this code is reached a second time?

```
private void checkMouse()
{
    mouseCommand mc = new mouseCommand();
    Thread oThread = new Thread(() => mc.leftClick(Mouse.GetState().X,Mouse.GetState().Y));
    oThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: I would probably use mutex locking for this problem.

Comment: If you use a BackgroundWorker then you can check to see if it's "free" to run again. See [BackgroundWorker.IsBusy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy(v=vs.110).aspx) - that is, there would be a *single* BGW and you would run if and only if it is not already running. You can also cancel a BGW (and if supported through-and-through the mouseCommand, it could be used to terminate the previous request early).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work for you?

```
private object lock_object - new object();
private Thread oThread = new Thread();

private void checkMouse()
{
    lock(lock_object)
    {
    if (oThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running) 
        {

            mouseCommand mc = new mouseCommand();
            oThread = new Thread(() => mc.leftClick(Mouse.GetState().X,Mouse.GetState().Y));
            oThread.Start();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You're locking on a thread (why?), and then changing the reference `oThread` to a different thread, so the next thread will try to lock on that instead, and always get the lock, because nothing is locking on it. Then the next thread will try to lock on **that** thread.

Comment: (And yet I still dislike that someone downvoted this without adding anything else; this answer is fixable, it just has a mistake in the choice of lock object).

Comment: @JonHanna You are correct, I didn't think of that when I wrote this. I was, admittedly, trying to give a simple answer that didn't have a new object just for locking on, and didn't give much thought to my choice of lock.

Comment: @JonHanna I changed my lock object. Aside from that, is there a problem with my code? I was thinking Mutex.TryEnter wouldn't be necessary because it should release the lock right after spawning the thread and therefor wouldn't hold it long. It is still something that would have to be tested in practice.

Comment: @JonHanna I suppose I should have added that I don't think spawning a new thread is a good way to handle a mouse event. The overhead is too high. I was giving a solution to their specific problem.

Comment: There's no need for `oThread` to be a field, a local would do (I'll point out that `Timer` objects can be different in interesting and confusing ways since our querent is new to threading and that might come up soon). Having it as a field is just a waste of time and memory, unless another thread wants to do something with it, and an opportunity for more bugs (if it's local, then the only place there can be a bug with it, is one method, so your risk of bugs is down and your ease of fixing is up). Beyond that, it's fine. If you want nitpicking, `oThread` is Hungarian-like, I'd just use `thread`

Comment: ... `mouseThread` or so on, but that was copying the OP's code, so I did exactly the same thing in my answer.

Comment: Also, yes, I agree with the overhead being way too high; it's a valid learning exercise, but it would cost way more than it gained to be a good idea in production code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this.

The simplest, and the first you should learn about when learning about threading is a lock. Have an `object` that you use to lock on this and any related actions that would also cause problem if they happened together:

```
private object lockObj = new object();
private static void DoLClick()
{
  lock(lockObj)
  {
    mouseCommand mc = new mouseCommand();
    mc.leftClick(Mouse.GetState().X,Mouse.GetState().Y));
  }
}
private void checkMouse()
{
    Thread oThread = new Thread(DoLClick);
    oThread.Start();
}
```

The benefit is that this keeps threads from stepping on each other toes.

The downside is the loss of concurrency (all these threads are waiting on each other, instead of doing something) and the risk of deadlock (if thread A has lock 1 and needs lock 2 and thread B has lock 2 and needs lock 1, you're stuck).

It remains the simplest approach. Often even if you're going to need to use another approach, it's well worth starting with some widely defined locks, and then changing to narrower locks (that is, locks that cover less code) or different approaches later.

Another possibility is to have a lock, but instead of using `lock(){}` to obtain it, you use `Monitor.TryEnter()` with a time-out (perhaps of zero) and just give up if you don't get it:

```
private object lockObj = new object();
private static void DoLClick()
{
  if(!Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj, 0))
    return; // Just do nothing if we're busy.
  try
  {
    mouseCommand mc = new mouseCommand();
    mc.leftClick(Mouse.GetState().X,Mouse.GetState().Y));
  }
  finally
  {
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
  }
}
private void checkMouse()
{
    Thread oThread = new Thread(DoLClick);
    oThread.Start();
}
```

The downside is that you don't get that second task done. The upside is that you often don't want something done if it's already being done, and you get that for free.

Some other approaches are a variant of this, where you've a thread-safe object describing tasks to do; it could be an integer count of actions that need doing that you use `Interlocked.Increment()`  and `Interlocked.Decrement()` to change, or a `ConcurrentQueue` of objects that describe the task that needs doing. Then you could have the thread that failed to get the lock add to that, and that which did get the lock take over that thread's work when it's finished. Or you could perhaps have a dedicated thread that just keeps looking for work to do, and waits on an `AutoResetEvent` whenever it runs out of work - threads giving it work (adding to the queue) set that event to make sure it's not just sitting doing nothing.

All these possibilities (and more) are worth learning about, and have their place, but the first suggestion with `lock` is the first to learn.

Comment: This is pretty good, I was using something similar to this previously however not quite what im after. I probably didn't explain myself very well. This would stop me running the thread twice at the same time however what I want is to kill the thread and start a new one rather than wait for it to finish running. The scenario I have is when you click you initiate path finding and the character moves to the selected location, however when you click somewhere else I need to kill the current thread moving the character and begin a new one for the new destination.